# how to access authentication timeout value from a template in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

**Setup**

During start-up of my Pyramid (version 1.10.5) application, I set an authentication timeout so that sessions expire after a duration of inactivity by the user, which works as expected.

```
login_timeout = 60 * 30 # 30 minutes
authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(auth_secret, 
                                           timeout=login_timeout, 
                                           reissue_time=reissue_time, 
                                           max_age=login_timeout)
config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
```

Now I am adding Javascript to my page templates to alert users when their session is about to expire, and I want to embed the same `login_timeout` value in the template without duplicating the value in my code.

**Question**

How can I access the timeout value of the authentication policy from a template or view in Pyramid?

**What I've Tried**

I have read through several pages of pyramid docs and source code (e.g. https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#authentication-policies), and I don't see how this value is accessible at request-time.

I inspected the `request` variable passed to the view function using a debugger. The value `request.session._timeout` is NOT it (I think that one might be a cookie expiration time).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First note that you were viewing the docs for Pyramid 2.0 (latest), not [1.10](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.10-branch/api/authentication.html#pyramid-authentication). That said, I think [`pyramid.registry.Registry.settings`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.10-branch/api/registry.html#pyramid.registry.Registry.settings) is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the correct version of documentation @steve-piercy. I looked all through the `request.registry.settings` object at runtime, and I didn't find anything related to the authentication timeout. I think I will need to find out exactly what is being set by `config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)` in order to get the value back at request-time. Or else I'll have to control the vaue in my INI file and make sure it gets stored in `request.registry.settings` so I can access it there. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up getting the authentication timeout in a view:

```
from pyramid.interfaces import IAuthenticationPolicy

@view_config(rounte_name='index', renderer='templates/index.html')
def index_view(request):
    authn_policy = request.registry.getUtility(IAuthenticationPolicy)
    auth_timeout = authn_policy.cookie.timeout

    return {'auth_timeout': auth_timeout}
```

Digging around, I found that the `request.registry` is made from a [Zope Component Registry](https://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/zope/interface/registry.html#Components), which allows getting registered utilities by specifying the interface. Since Pyramid's `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` implements the `IAuthenticationPolicy`, that's the one to use here.

Since I want this value to be available on all requests in all views/templates, I later moved the code from above into a custom root factory, so it's no longer needed in the view:

```
class Root(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        authn_policy = request.registry.getUtility(IAuthenticationPolicy)
        request.auth_timeout = authn_policy.cookie.timeout
```

The root factory gets set at application startup:

```
config.set_root_factory(Root)
```

Now I can access it in any template:

```
<script>
    var auth_timeout = {{request.auth_timeout}};
    // ...
</script>
```